# TableView with background image

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimage

I want to have an image behind my tableview, i added a UIImage behind and set the tableview background to clear, in IB it shows the image behind the tableview but when i run it i get a black background, anybody can help me with this?

Comment: do you want the background to scroll or to be fixed on the tableview?

Comment: Please make sure you have connected delegate and Datasource to the tableView in IBOutlet !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take off the image and add this code to your viewDidLoad:

```
UIView *patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
patternView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.tableView.backgroundView = patternView;
```

this is the way to add a fixed image as a background of a tableview.

Comment: Another quick question, i tried to set the position of the table view in IB but it doesn't work, do you know how to do this programmatically by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

or you could do that without subclassing by simply assigning the tableview's backgroundView property in your main controller class...

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in `-(void)viewDidLoad` method

```
self.tblView= [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17,110, 280.0, 265) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tblView.delegate=self;
    self.tblView.dataSource=self;
    //self.tblView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.tblView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tblView];
```